# How to parse first 6 strings of a line

Tags: java, string

I have a line from a dataset like this : vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,low,unacc`
and I am trying to read the first 6 strings

```
vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,low
```

to a String array and the last String

```
unacc
```

to another String variable.

I tried to use `String[] arr = line.split(",")` and then do`String var = arr[5]` but this also stored the last string to the array.

Does anyone has another idea ?

Comment: So you're effectively asking how to remove the final element from an array, I think.

Comment: Arrays are zero-based, thus `arr[6]` is the 7th string, not the 6th. "*[...] but this also stored the last string to the array.*" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth or maybe a better way to do it

Comment: But I want the array the final element of the array to be removed

Comment: I an trying to find something better than just Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length-1)

Comment: @JohnDuke Arrays are not resizable. You can simply all entries after the 6th to `null`, but I would strongly advice against that since this only opens possibilities for `NullPointerException`s. Besides, what is wrong with `Arrays.copyOf(...)`?

Comment: @Turing85 I am not wrong, it cant be used for string arrays.

Comment: @JohnDuke It can be used with `String`-arrays, [@Ward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48042656/4216641) is proof of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.split()` to split input into an array,  `Arrays.copyOfRange()` to copy first elements into new array, and `String.join()` to join those parts to a new `String`.

```
String input = "vhigh,vhigh,2,2,small,low,unacc";

String[] inputParts = input.split(",");
String firstSix = String.join(",", Arrays.copyOfRange(inputParts, 0, 6));
String last = inputParts[6];

System.out.println(firstSix);
System.out.println(last);
```